# How to access an array located in class a from class b realtime

Tags: python, computer-science

I am learning  python now and got it in to this weird issue.  I have an array in a class named A,  I am using that array as a queue..  I want to access that array in class A from class B and  class C realtime. For example if class B adds something to that array in Class A I wanted to see that change in Class C when I print the array from Class C

```
class a:
   array = [1,2] 
 def return_array(self) :
   return self.array
 def add_to_array(val) 
     self.insert(val,0)

class b:
  def b(self) :
    d = a() 
     d.add_to_array(0)

ci=b()
b. b() 

class c:
  def __init__(self) :
     cd = a() 
     print(cd.return_array() 
     #prints []  I want it to print [0,1,2]
c=c()
```

I want it realtime.   Because other class has to see what's going on in that

Comment: Input? Desired Output? Code?

Comment: Updated @schwobaseggl

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code to this:

```
class a:
    array = [1,2] 
def return_array(self):
    print(self.array)
def add_to_array(self, val):
    a.array.insert(0,val)

class b(a):
    pass

ab = b()
ab.add_to_array(0)

class c(a):
    pass

ac = c()
ac.return_array()
```

**Explanation:**
`self.insert()` function in your code needs to be changed to specify which data member you are referring to in the class.

Further, in Python:
`my_object.method("foo")` is interpreted as `MyClass.method(my_object, "foo")`
Therefore, in `d.add_to_array(0)` you are passing one parameter whereas it expects you to pass two parameters.